# Visual Studio 2022 not allowing c++20 even though i have got /std:c++20

Tags: visual-studio

I have got the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ranges>
#include<string>

auto f(auto& x, auto& y)
{
    std::cout << x << y << "\n";
}

struct s
{
    int x;
    std::string y;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << "\n";
}
```

and I have the /std:c++20 in my configuration:

```
ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)
```

I have tried using that and I have the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

```
Error (active)  E1598   'auto' is not allowed here  Project1    C:\Users\robert\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp   5
```

```
1>Source.cpp
1>The contents of <ranges> are available only with C++20 or later.
1>C:\Users\rober\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp(5,15): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
1>C:\Users\rober\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Source.cpp(5,24): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
```

I am expecting my code to run fine because all of the c++20 headers are fine like std::ranges etc. It is by default on Visual Studio 2022 that the language is C++14 but I do not know why it is not running. So, it just resulted in the error shown above.

I have seen the other question about auto is not allowed here but that was in c++17 and the answer to that was it will come with c++20, but i have /std:c++20 in my projects -> propeties bit of visual studio 2022

Comment: Compiling with MSVC v19.latest along with `/std:c++20` [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/fz57KWTeb). What specific compiler version?

Comment: @CoryKramer how would I access that information?

Comment: Works fine in VS2022.  Project > Properties, pay attention to the comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  Select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" before changing the property.

Comment: @HansPassant Where is the "All Configurations" and "All Platforms"?